# IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate() in android java

Tags: android

I am facing this exception .I checked many solutions but can't figure out what's the problem in my code. This MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


private Button button , button1;
private ListView lv;
final String[] listitems = new String[2];
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_list = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    lv  =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.android_listView1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new Fetch().execute("Hardware");

            //populateList(listitems);
        }                   

    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
        }                   
    });

}

public void populateList(Hardware h)
{
    listitems[0] = h.device;
    listitems[1] = h.manufacturer;
    adapter_list=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitems);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter_list);
}
```

}

I have also a class which extends AsyncTask :

```
public class Fetch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Hardware>  {
@Override
protected Hardware doInBackground(String... str) {


        Hardware h = new Hardware();
        h.manufacturer = "Hello";
        h.device = "Hello";

        return h;       
}   
 protected void onPostExecute(Hardware h) {
     MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
     m.populateList(h);
 }
```

}

This line is excuting the background proces in MainActivity :

```
new Fetch().execute("Hardware");
```

I need help in this , Thanks in advance

**Log Cat Output**

```
06-28 09:49:47.878: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6925): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-28 09:49:49.777: D/AndroidRuntime(6925): Shutting down VM
06-28 09:49:49.777: W/dalvikvm(6925): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3526)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:271)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:125)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at com.example.first.MainActivity.populateList(MainActivity.java:87)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at com.example.first.Fetch.onPostExecute(Fetch.java:38)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at com.example.first.Fetch.onPostExecute(Fetch.java:1)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
06-28 09:49:49.788: E/AndroidRuntime(6925):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: LogCat output might be useful. Looks like You're trying to getSystemService() from some place before onCreate() call. Also, activities is designed NOT to be used in new MainActivity() way.

Comment: Yes that's what I am asking , I have only four lines above onCreate() call , and it seems like that no line is trying to getSystemService()

Comment: @sandrstar I think there is a problem in new Fetch().execute("Hardware"); , I commented it , and app is running correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Hardware h) {
     **MainActivity m = new MainActivity();**
     m.populateList(h);
 }
```

Activity life cycle is taken care by Android itself. You should not instantiate the Activity like this. Rather pass the activity instance as parameter to the AsyncTask. And access it

`onPostExecute()` method

Comment: How do I pass the activity instance ?

Comment: Well there are many ways one of them is , to have a singleton class to accessible throughout the app and you can access it from AsyncTask class

Comment: You can just introduce constructor for Fetch class and pass Activity in there.