# System services not available to Activities before onCreate(), but no properties instantiated

Tags: android, system-services

I am trying to create a service which checks if the device has an active internet connection and reports it. I have absolutely no clue what's wrong with my code.

I know this question has been asked [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=system%20services%20not%20available%20before%20onCreate%28%29), but most answers, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17362221/507738), state

- that one cannot create an activity using the `new` keyword (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17362221/507738));
- that properties which are instantiated also are the cause of the problem (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23441738/507738)).

Now as far as I know, I avoided forementioned causes. This is my simplified code:

- **MyActivity**

  ```
  public MyActivity extends SuperActivity {

      // No properties are instantiated
      // No onCreate(Bundle) method

  }
  ```
- **SuperActivity**

  ```
  public SuperActivity extends Activity {

      ApplicationManager appMgr;
      UIManager uiMgr;
      // No properties are instantiated, only declared

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstance);

          this.appMgr = new ApplicationManager(this);
          this.appMgr.getUIManager().init();
      }
  }
  ```
- **ApplicationManager**

  ```
  public ApplicationManager {

      // No properties are instantiated
      SuperActivity activity;
      Thread serviceThread;
      UIManager uiMgr;

      ApplicationManager(SuperActivity activity) {
          this.activity = activity;
          this.uiMgr = new UIManager(this);
      }

      void initService() {
          this.serviceThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ConnectionService.class);
                  intent.putExtra("CONTEXT", getActivity());
                  intent.putExtra("ALLOW_MOBILE_CONNECTION", true);
                  getActivity().startService(intent);
              }
          });
      }

      void startService() {
          this.serviceThread.start();
      }

      UIManager getUIManager() {
          return this.uiMgr;
      }

      SuperActivity getActivity() {
          return this.activity;
      }
  }
  ```
- **UIManager**

  ```
  public class UIManager {

      // No properties are instantiated

      void init() {
          getApplicationManager().initService();
          getApplicationManager().startService(); // <-- FIRST MARKER,
                                                  //     see below
      }

  }
  ```
- **ConnectionService**

  ```
  public class ConnectionService {

      @Override
      protected Bundle onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          Bundle params = intent.getExtras();
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          Context cntxt = (Context) params.getSerializable("CONTEXT");
          try {
              boolean wifi =
                  NetworkUtils.hasWifiCon(cntxt); // <-- SECOND MARKER,
                                                  //     see below

              ...
          }
          catch (SocketException exc) { ... }
          return bundle;
      }
  }
  ```

The error occurs on the line denoted by SECOND MARKER, which gets the system connection service and checks for wifi. This is the service which is not allowed to be called before `onCreate()`.

Furthermore, if I remove or comment the line denoted by FIRST MARKER, the error is gone, but also, of course, the service is not started.

What could be the problem?

Comment: One problem is that your code will not compile. `ApplicationManager` does not have a `getActivity()` method.

Comment: @CommonsWare I forgot to add it, due to the process of simplifying the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass around a `Context` by serializing it in a bundle.

In an `IntentService` which I assume your `ConnectionService` is, just use `this` for a valid `Context`.